# If Statement Conversion From C to Assembly(Motorola 68k)

Tags: c, if-statement, assembly, branch, 68000

I'm given a IF statement like this:

```
if( (Ch > ‘g’) && (Ch < ‘m’)) || ((A>=0) && (A<=100))
    condition = 1;
else
    condition = 0;
```

Where Ch is a char, A is a int, and condition is a short int.

I'm trying to put this into assembly language as such:

```
Org $8000
CLR.W DO
CLR.W D1
CMPI.B #$67,ch
BGT ;something here...

Org   $9000
ch    DC.B  'a'
A     DC.L   0
condition  DS.W  1
```

I believe I've gotten the first if condition, where 67 is the hex value for the ascii code, for the letter 'g'. But I have no idea how to implement the AND statement here, I guess the or statement could be treated like an else? Since either one part of the if executes or the other does. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to draw a flowchart.

Comment: I already have, it's not exactly helping :s

Comment: If you really have a flowchart that works, it should be a trivial matter to turn that into assembly.

Comment: Ahh I get it now, I'm just wondering now if I compare 0 and the int A, do I have to use CMPI.L ? or CMPI.B ?

Comment: Since it's an `int`, you want `CMPI.L`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have a flowchart that works, it should be a trivial matter to turn that into assembly.

I am not going to draw it for you, just give a pseudocode rendering of it:

```
    if Ch <= 'g' goto check_second_term
    if Ch < 'm' goto result_one

check_second_term:
    if A < 0 goto result_zero
    if A > 100 goto result_zero
result_one:
    condition := 1
    goto done
result_zero:
    condition := 0
done:
```

I trust you can turn these into `cmp`+`bcc` pairs.

Comment: Hmm just noticed you inverted all the operations, is their a reason for that?

Comment: I didn't invert **all** :) The reason is that it worked out more conveniently this way. For `&&`  you can easily see that the condition fails if any of the terms fail.